# NSMutableDictionary does not add elements

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, nsdictionary

I don't understand why it can't add element to my dictionary. In my console, i always get the "It's not here!" I have posted my code below

```
//.m  
#import "ExercisesViewController.h"
#import "STATableViewController.h"

@implementation ExercisesViewController
@synthesize descriptionLabel = _descriptionLabel;
@synthesize descriptionsDictionary = _descriptionsDictionary;
@synthesize objName = _objName;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
[super viewDidLoad];
_descriptionsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[_descriptionsDictionary setObject:@"foo" forKey:@"bar"];

if([[_descriptionsDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"foo"])
    NSLog(@"It's here!");
else
    NSLog(@"It's not here!");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding the value `foo` for the key `bar` but then checking the keys for `foo`. Reverse the key/value you are adding:

```
[_descriptionsDictionary setObject:@"bar" forKey:@"foo"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[_descriptionsDictionary allKeys]
```

will return an array of  keys.
Here it is (@"bar"). And from NSArray Class reference it is said that the method, "containsObject:"

> This method determines whether anObject is present in the array by sending an isEqual: message to each of the array’s objects (and passing anObject as the parameter to each isEqual: message).

In this case the method containsObject: checks

```
[@"bar" isEqual:@"foo"]
```

The result is false in this case. This is why you are getting "It's not here!"

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if([[_descriptionsDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"bar"]) {
    NSLog(@"It's here!");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"It's not here!");
}
```

allKeys gives you a NSArray with the keys of the dictionary, allValues gives you its entries